# Codeigniter, loading views inside views, variables doesn't reset each time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the latest stable version of Codeigniter.

Here's part of the controller:

```
$data = array(
    'tracks' => $this->tracks_model->get(NULL, 'start_date'),
    'longest_distance' => $this->tracks_model->get(10, 'distance'),
    'longest_time' => $this->tracks_model->get(10, 'moving_time') 
);

$this->load->view('statistics_view', $data);
```

and here's part of the code inside the file statistics_view.php:

```
<section>

    <h3>Section 1</h3>

    <?php $this->load->view('podium_view', array('tracks' => $longest_time, 'unit' => 'ore', 'function' => 'minutes_to_hours')) ?>

</section>

<section>

    <h3>Section 2</h3>

    <?php $this->load->view('podium_view', array('tracks' => $longest_distance, 'unit' => 'km')) ?>

</section>
```

I've noticed that in the 2nd loaded view (inside section 2), the variable $function is still set from section 1, and the other values (traks, unit) are the one I passed.

Why the variable function is still set in the second view?
Shouldn't be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter uses extract in order to convert the array of variables you are passing
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php
Extract keep adding variable to the symbol table and the view is just included as a PHP file.
So the variable scope is the same and you will have access to all the variables defined early. Default behaviour of extract is it overrides if a conflict is found.
If you want to reset, you will have to pass some value.

```
<?php $this->load->view('podium_view', array('tracks' => $longest_distance, 'unit' => 'km', 'function'=>'')) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. In your opinion, is there a more elegant approach to load views inside views passing variables?

Answer (score 3):

In Codeigniter 3 you can also reset variables in view using method

```
$this->load->clear_vars();
```

[See it in documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html?highlight=clear_vars#CI_Loader::clear_vars)

Comment: says the edit queue is full so those looking for the working link 
 here it is http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?highlight=clear_vars#CI_Loader::clear_vars